# Exact behavior of the -finline-limit GCC compiler option

Tags: c, performance, inline-functions

I am using GCC's `-finline-limit=N` compiler option. I am compiling my code and profiling it to check for reduction of CPU cycles. When I increase *N*, ideally, I should see a decrease in the number of cycles as larger functions get inlined. But I am seeing increase in the CPU cycles. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple parameters (--param) for inlining in gcc. finline-limit uses some of them.

You can find the parameters here:

[gcc optimize-options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) (search for max-inline-insns-single)

You can get some information on GCCs inline-heuristik from the sourcecode:
[ipa-inline-analysis.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/2cc80ac37074949b269d06bd7b3b8e61932eb0be/gcc/ipa-inline-analysis.c) (the comment at the top)

Note: Reducing function calls, branching etc. via inlining does not always reduce CPU cycles. Setting finline-limit to a large number can make things worse. Using `__attribute__ ((flatten))` on functions can produce better results. All optimizing parameters can produce different results depending on your instruction sets and compiler version.

Comment: Please let me know if there is any specific case where inlining actually worsens cycles